# How do you rebuild a string using StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, substring, stringbuilder, indexof

Im trying to rebuild a string using StringBuilder. I'm a little unsure of which method to use to get the "'," inserted back into the same place. In the code below I'm using the 
"insert(int dstOffset, CharSequence s, int start, int end)" method. My code doesn't contain any errors however it doesn't run properly.

Please note I will also be escaping characters (i.e., =) in the string but I havent written that part of the code yet. Currently I'm trying to learn how to split the string and then rebuild it.

Thanks

```
public class StringTestProgram 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";
    String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");
    for (String stringoutput : stringData) 
    {
      System.out.print(stringoutput);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stringoutput); 
      CharSequence charAdded = ",";
      sb.insert(6,charAdded,0,12); 
      System.out.print(sb.toString()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Revised code

```
public class StringTestProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {

String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";
System.out.println(relativeDN);

//Split String
String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");


{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
CharSequence charAdded = ",";

// loop thru each element of the array
for (int place = 0; place < stringData.length; place++) {
System.out.println(stringData[place]);

{

int eq = relativeDN.indexOf('=');
String sub = relativeDN.substring(0, eq);           
System.out.println(sub);

}


// append element to the StringBuilder
sb.append(stringData[place]);

// avoids adding an extra ',' at the end
if (place < stringData.length - 1)

// if not at the last element, add the ',' character
sb.append(charAdded);
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());

}
}
}
```

Im new to stackoverflow and I'm not sure if its ok to ask this question in this thread or if I should create a seperate thread for this question. If possible please advise.

The code above now splits the string at the "," character. It also rebuilds the 
string back to its original state. I would also like to use the indexof and .substring 
methods to get the string value after the "=" sign. Currently my program only outputs
the first two characters of the initial string value before the "=" sign. Not sure where 
in my code I'm making an error. Any help would be appreciated.

My Current Output
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def
cn=abc
cn
dn=xyz
cn
ou=abc/def
cn
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def

Desired Output
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def
cn=abc
abc
dn=xyz
xyz
ou=abc/def
abc/def
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks to everyone for contributing several answers to my question as well as taking the time to explain the code. Your help was and is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code

```
public class StringTestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";

        String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        CharSequence charAdded = ",";

        for (int i = 0; i < stringData .length; i++) { //walk over each element of the array
            System.out.println(stringData[i]);
            sb.append(stringData[i]); // append element to the StringBuilder

            if (i < stringData.length - 1) //avoids adding an extra ',' at the end
                sb.append(charAdded); // if not at the last element, add the ',' character
        }

        System.out.print(sb.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Here you will reconstruct the original string exactly as it was (i.e. without adding a trailing ','):

```
cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def
```

**UPDATE**: In the for loop I just walk over every element of the array that stores the splitted String and append the elements to the StringBuilder instance one by one. After appending each element I check if we are currently at the last element of the array. If not, I append the ',' character.

Comment: This code gives me the output I was looking for. If its not asking to much can you explain whats going on within the for statement?

Comment: @Papitulo sure, see the update to the answer. I have also added more comments to the code. If you need extra help, please make me know.

Comment: @Papitulo - you are welcome. By the way, I would also appreciate if accepted my answer, of course if you find this suitable :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this pre Java 8 is to use 1 StringBuilder for all the elements and add Strings to the builder by using the  `append()` method

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String stringoutput : stringData) {
   builder.append(stringoutput).append(',');
}

//have an extra trailing comma so remove it
//use length -1 as end coord because it's exclusive
String result = builder.substring(0, builder.length() -1);
```

If you are using Java 8 you can use the new  Stream API and `Collectors.joining()`

```
String result = Arrays.stream(relativeDN.split(","))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Why you `substring` if you don't have to? This makes your code slower.

Comment: @martijnn2008 no it doesn't. `builder.toString()` and `builder.substring()` both call `new String(chararray, start, end)`. the only difference between the 2 calls is what the values for start and end are.

Comment: Ah, I forgot we were using a `StringBuilder`. Then I think it's smart to use the `StringBuilder.substring` method.

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing `sb` every time you enter the loop, meaning that you're disposing of your `StringBuilder` every time you enter the loop and recreate it with only the next subtring.

Fixed:

```
String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";

String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
CharSequence charAdded = ",";

for (String stringoutput : stringData) {
    System.out.print(stringoutput);
    sb.append(stringoutput).append(charAdded); 
}

sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);

System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: You are forgetting the `,` that you are leaving at the end

Comment: Fixed, now the last ',' is discarded

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
for (String stringoutput : stringData) 
    sb.append(stringoutput).append(',');
```

Fixed: Using this approach, you would have to remove the last `,`

```
String result = sb.toString().substring(0,sb.toString().length()-1);

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Now you also have a `,` at the end of the output. That is not something the OP wants.

Comment: True. I fixed it by removing the last `,`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the other answers that there would be an extra comma at the end. You have to use a prefix variable and then change it in the loop so that there won't be an extra comma.

```
String relativeDN = "cn=abc,dn=xyz,ou=abc/def";
String[] stringData = relativeDN.split(",");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String prefix = "";
for (String element : stringData) {
    sb.append(prefix);
    prefix=",";
    sb.append(element);
}
String output = sb.toString();
```

Inside the loop the prefix is appended, but on the first time through the loop the prefix is set to empty quotes so that there won't be a comma before the first element. Next prefix is changed to a comma so that in the next turn through the loop a comma will be added after the first element. Lastly, the element is added. This results in the correct output because the comma is added before the element, but only after the first iteration.

Comment: This code also gives the desired output. Can you please expalin what the code withing the for statement does?